# Word boundary (\b) metacharacter bug in Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, regex, dreamweaver, word-boundary

I'm a newbie in programming languages and regular expressions.
Currently I'm using Dreamweaver CS6 and I was practicing with it's Find and Replace tool.
When I use the regular expression

```
\b\w{4}
```

instead of matching only the first 4 letters of any word that is composed by 4 or more letters, it matches also any other 4-letter sequence in the words that have more than 8 letters.

For example, in the word `transparent` it highlights `tran` and `spar`.

But if I use the regex

```
\w{4}\b
```

it works as it should and maches only the last 4 letters of any word that is composed by 4 or more letters.
For example, in the word transparent highlights only rent.

If I'm not mistaken, Dreamweaver uses the javascript regex flavor.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you mean `\w` in your second regex? Is this a typo in the question or in the original regex you tried?

Comment: This seems like a bug in Dreamweaver. `\b\w{4}` should not match `spar` in `transparent` assuming the usual definition of `\b` as a word boundary anchor.

Comment: Well, it's not a JS issue: `var str = "I'm a newbie in programming languages and regular expressions. Currently I'm using Dreamweaver CS6 and I was practicing with it's Find and Replace tool. When I use the regular expression"; str.match(/\b\w{4}/g); ["newb", "prog", "lang", "regu", "expr", "Curr", "usin", "Drea", "prac", "with", "Find", "Repl", "tool", "When", "regu", "expr"]`.

Comment: I've corrected the error. Thanks @ajp15243.